# MySQL regex of single diacritic character returns other characters

Tags: mysql, regex

I am having a problem with regex searches in MySQL on certain diacritic characters. A search for a specific character returns other diacritic characters.

Table with schema:

```
CREATE TABLE names (first_name varchar(20)) DEFAULT 
CHARSET=utf8;
```

and rows:

```
INSERT INTO names (first_name) VALUES ('Cătălïn');
INSERT INTO names (first_name) VALUES ('Kēlee');
```

running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE LOWER(first_name) REGEXP '[ē]+';
```

should return:

```
first_name
----------
Kēlee
```

Instead, it returns:

```
first_name
----------
Cătălïn
Kēlee
```

Am I missing something here? Running on 5.7

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/059827/1/0 (this maxes out at 5.6)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM names WHERE LOWER(first_name) like '%ē%';`

Comment: Strangely, if I change query to `SELECT * FROM names WHERE LOWER(first_name) REGEXP 'ē+';` it works.

Comment: There are a lot of strangenesses when you try to use REGEXP on utf8 encoding.  The regexp is strange too:  You are asking if there is one or more `ē` in a row and checking for a single character in `[]`.  Neither of those adds anything to the query (if it worked).  For simply checking for `ē`:  `WHERE HEX(first_name) REGEXP "C493"